# do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused

Tags: connection

I had been running a time-consuming background program via a bash script on a linux server. In the same bash script, I set the notification by "set -o notify" so I could know when the background job was done.

Probably yesterday night the notification popped out to say the background job was done, and after that there were following error messages, which I am not sure if occured immediately after the background job finished or a while later, since I was not at my terminal at that time:

> do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
>
> do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
>
> do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused

I also redirected the stdout output of my background job to a log file which seems to say the program was not finished as expected but terminated midway.

Could you explain the meaning of the error message? If possible,what kinds of problem could I possibly met? Could it be that the administrator placed some restriction on the resources that I can use on that server?

Thanks and regards!

---

UPDATE:

the same hard drive is mounted via NFS over several servers including the one mentioned above. I just found a similar but different error occur on the other server:

> do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Timed out

This error and the previous error seem not affect the programs that are running. BTW my program has IO operations.

Comment: is your script using sudo by any chance?

Comment: @stsquad It is really a long time ago. I forgot.

Comment: that's a shame. We have a build script that uses sudo and I've noticed it throws these errors while the sudo commands are running. Obviously they trigger NIS queries when checking the user ID for sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have NIS running and it has failed, pretty normal with NIS in my experience :-).  If it is still happening, maybe try `/etc/init.d/ypbind restart` ?  Perhaps this box is bound to Active directory and the connect failed ...

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is still happening. I tried */etc/init.d/ypbind restart* but "bash: /etc/init.d/ypbind: No such file or directory
".

Answer (score 0):

had this issue on a machine where the /var filesystem had been offlined due to disk faults -
ypbind would restart, but couldn't update it's 'binding' file, and so triggered errors

after reboot / fsck and resolving the filesystem problem, the issue was resolved.

possibly permissions or filesystem isues in /var related here?